# Why is scala Await.result timing out in repl when passed the same future twice?

Tags: scala, concurrency

I found this a bit confusing. I thought futures in scala are inmutable containers that once set, always return the same value.

So I have a future:

```
val y = future {Thread.sleep(1000); 1};
```

Now when i immediately (before the future resolves) pass it to `Await.result` block twice:

```
Await.result(for (r1 <- y; r2 <- y) yield (r1, r2), 60 seconds)
```

I get a `TimetoutException`.

However if i do it once the future is resolved, everything works fine and returns `(1,1)` as expected.

What is the reason of this behavior?

Edit:
I'm using implicit `ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` and `scala.concurrent` @ scala 2.10.3

Edit2:
If I create another future instance doing the same thing and do Await.result on them both it doesn't block.

Comment: If there's something `async/await` in C# taught me, it's that mixing synchronous and asynchronous waiting is a bad idea that more often than not leads to deadlocks. I suspect a deadlock somewhere between blocking `Await.result`, asynchronous future and blocking `Thread.sleep`.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek yeah it's oversimplification, but since 99% of examples with futures use `Thread.sleep` I thought there should be no issues. Especially since there's no way to be sure that a library code I'm using in my future doesn't call `Thread.sleep` on it's own.

Comment: Those examples are using `Thread.sleep` simply because there is no direct tool to schedule/pause a future in the standard library, so thi is the simplest way to demonstrate something that requires such a scheduling. But you should absolutly not use it in production code as it will block a whole thread, entirely defeating the performance advantage of using future, PLUS potentially blocking other unsuspecting futures from executing (when all future threads are sleeping). Just don't do it.

Comment: Except when you have to do file I/O or DNS or JDBC or call a blocking library like the various AWS SDK classes or … It's all well and good to say "just don't do that," but it is often a practical necessity. When those cases arise, you need to create your own `ExecutionContex` backed by an appropriate `ThreadPool` to make sure your system does not stall, underutilize the CPU or otherwise misbehave.

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles I know i shouldn't use that in production, hard to be sure if some third party solution doesn't do that. Also I'd like to know why is this happening? Am I just unlucky enough so that all the futures get executed by the same thread in the global execution context? That would explain the behavior. Also this happens even when Thread.sleep exits, so i don't know what can really block things here.

Comment: i.e if I put println("whatever") after the Thread.sleep it prints (immediately after 1s), so the thread isn't locked forever.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me (no timeout), scala 2.10 and akka 2.2.0

Comment: @Randall Schulz: Of course, you can do it if you take care to use a separate thread pool, I've done just that myself more than I can count. When I say "don't do it", this is really what I mean: don't do what you OP has just done. You can always find counter arguments to anything using "ifs" and "buts". OP is not using a dedicated thread pool and calls Thread.sleep in a future. I definitely stand by my advice: just don't. And actually I would even recommend to not create your own ExecutionContext either, but just execute your blocking code in a dedicated thread and then fulfill a promise.

Comment: @Noah it's scala.concurrent @ scala 2.10.3. I tested it in repl, curiously if i run it as a script it doesn't block. What gives?

Comment: @soulcheck must be too early in the morning, yeah I'm using 2.10.2 concurrent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't want to start threads from class initializers is that cycles in classloading will block. A Scala object is just an instance created in a static block. The closure's reference to y is a cycle. In 2.11, use -Yrepl-class-based to help it work.

Lets examine the stack trace for the hang when the closure class needs `X.z`:

```
apm@mara:~$ goof
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-RC3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import duration._
import duration._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> object X { val y = Future { 9 } ; val z = Future { 7 } ; val r = Await.result(for (a <- y; b <- z) yield (a+b), 5.seconds) }
defined object X

scala> X.r
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$X$
    at $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$X$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:14)
    at $line15.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$X$$anonfun$3.apply(<console>:14)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$AdaptedForkJoinTask.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:121)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [5 seconds]
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
  at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$result$1.apply(package.scala:111)
  at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$DefaultBlockContext$.blockOn(BlockContext.scala:53)
  at scala.concurrent.Await$.result(package.scala:111)
  ... 34 elided
```

And just to show it working:

```
apm@mara:~$ goof -Yrepl-class-based
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-RC3 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import duration._
import duration._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> object X { val y = Future { 9 } ; val z = Future { 7 } ; val r = Await.result(for (a <- y; b <- z) yield (a+b), 5.seconds) }
defined object X

scala> X.r
res0: Int = 16
```

Comment: I'm accepting this as together with your commend under Regis's answer it's quite complete and includes workaround. Your comment under his answer should be included here though.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be an artifact of executing it in the REPL.
You can even reproduce it using 2 separate future instances, without any call to `Thread.sleep`,
and using only pre-fulfilled futures (which means that there is not even any future thread involed).
Yes, seriously:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import duration._
import ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
val x = Future.successful(1)
val y = Future.successful(2)
Await.result(x.flatMap{_ => y.map{ _ => 0 } }, Duration(10, SECONDS)) // triggers a timeout
```

Interestingly this does not trigger any timeout if you change the last line to this:

```
Await.result(x.flatMap{_ => Future.successful(2).map{ _ => 0 } }, Duration(10, SECONDS))
```

It seems that the culprint is that your whole code snippet, when evaled in the REPL, is actually wrapped in an object.
This means that `x` and `y` here are actually members of the object, rather than local variables
More importantly, the call to Await is now part of the constructor of this wrapper object. 
For some reason that I have yet to investigate, it seems to be the fact that the call to `Await` is done in a constructor that triggers the blocking 
(you can verify it easily by wrapping this call in a dummy class and instantiating it).

Comment: Yes, the reason you don't want to start threads from class initializers is that cycles in classloading will block.  A Scala object is just an instance created in a static block.  The closure's reference to y is a cycle. In 2.11, use `-Yrepl-class-based` to help it work.